# How to update a value in a CHashMap based on the value itself?

Tags: rust, concurrency, hashmap

I am trying to create a concurrent hash map that stores Strings as keys and i32s as values. Essentially, I am parsing a large corpus of text and every time the same String is encountered, I add 1 to value that String maps to. Using HashMap I can do this just fine, but it is not concurrent, and I'd like to parallelize this.

The problem I seem to be encountering is that I need to read the value, then update that value. Since CHashMap locks the value (as it should), this is not possible. However, if values cannot be updated then CHashMap is useless, which implies that I must be doing something wrong. Here is the relevant code. Note that the function "token_split" works and the string parsing in general works just fine. This algorithm has been tested thoroughly in a single-threaded environment using HashMap. What you see here is that same single-threaded code, but this time using CHashMap instead of HashMap. The text corpus is inside of a big vector.

```
let mut d1: CHashMap<String,i32> = CHashMap::new();
    let sep = Regex::new(r"([ ]+)").unwrap();
    for i in 0..la.len() {
        let strs: Vec<String> = token_split(&la[i],&sep);
        if let mut Some(count) = d1.get_mut(&strs[0]){
            d1.insert(strs[0].clone(),count+1);
        }
        else{
            d1.insert(strs[0].clone(),1);
        }
    }
```

When compiled (or when using cargo check), the error is:

```
error[E0369]: cannot add `{integer}` to `WriteGuard<'_, String, i32>`
  --> src/main.rs:61:35
   |
61 |             d1.insert(strs[0].clone(),count+1);
   |                                       -----^- {integer}
   |                                       |
   |                                       WriteGuard<'_, String, i32>
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code? If possible, please post a reproducible code. If it doesn't compiler, please post the full error from `cargo check`.

Comment: The `chashmap` crate looks very old and perhaps unmaintained. I'd recommend [`dashmap`](https://docs.rs/dashmap).

Answer (score 1):

To access the value guarded by the `WriteGuard` dereference it:

```rust
d1.insert(strs[0].clone(), *count + 1);
```

However, this is still incorrect as it may deadlock. You already have a guard for the entry, just modify it:

```rust
*count += 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, that did seem to do it. I've also changed to dashmap. Out of curiosity, how did you know that? I couldn't find that information anywhere (at least, if it was there I couldn't understand it)

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky How did I know what? That you can dereference? I looked at the docs for `WriteGuard` and see that it impls `Deref` and `DerefMut`. But I also guessed that, since I know how concurrency primitives work in Rust.

Comment: I've got a lot to learn then. Thanks again!